# Check if tab is disabled using jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs

Using jquery, I want to check if a particular tab is disabled or not.  I've researched the topic and tried different suggestions, but have not been able to get any of them to work.  When I try the one below in my .js file, I get the error on the "return" line in the function:  "Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'"

```
if (isTabDisabled(2)){
}
else {
    SetAppointmentNumberDialogText();
}

function isTabDisabled(index) {
    return $.inArray(index, $("#tabs").tabs("option", "disabled")) > -1;
}
```

Finally, is this the right approach, or is there a better way to check to see if the tab is disabled using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite explicit, you first need to initialize your tabs before using them:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

Then, later in your code, you can test the tabs state:

```
if ($.inArray(1, $("#tabs").tabs("option", "disabled")) > -1) {
    // Tab 1 is disabled
}
```